# Images not showing up with https

Tags: php, ssl, image, https

Suddenly, my images are not showing up on my site when accessing https pages.  No change in my code.  My host did have to recompile their ftp service with SSL support after my request (so I could ftpes my site).  Can't thing of anything else that would affect my SSL cert.  Same thing happens on FF and IE and on different computers.

Comment: What does "not showing up" mean ? Are your images getting you a 404 error ? a 403 ? Something else ? Can you procide an URL that shows the problem, as an example ?

Comment: I think for some of the resources he is getting access denied.

Comment: The source of the page includes the image references, but the image is not visible in the browser.  No errors that I can find.  Try this: https://www.scfootball.org.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I go to your website *( https://www.scfootball.org/ )*, I don't see the images, as you said : I get a [403 (Forbidden) error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) for each one of those -- I can see this using the "Net" tab of the Firefox extension [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), for instance.

If I try to see an image directly, without going trough the site *(for instance : https://www.scfootball.org/widgets/GulloParkHeader.png )*, then, I can see the image.

 *If you try, make sure you copy-paste the URL to a new tab/window, and not just click on it*

Which means there is some kind of trouble between the website and the access to the images ; not on the images themselves.

If I disable the [referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer) in firefox *(the [web developper toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) extension allows that easily)* and refresh your website's webpage, the images appear.

If I re-enable the referer, and refresh again, then the images don't appear anymore.

Which means there is something, related to the referer, that prevents the images from being sent, and returns a 403 error instead.

Just a wild guess : maybe there's a `.htaccess` in your `widgets` directory *(or somewhere else)* that prevents images from being served, if the referer doesn't correspond to a specific domain ?

Considering the images are displayed on the site when I access it without HTTPS *(i.e. with an URL such as http://www.scfootball.org/index2.php )*, maybe there is a "protection" in place so your images are not displayed if the Referer is not that non-https website... And that "protection" has not been updated when you switched to HTTPS ?

*(I've seen that kind of "protection" used to prevent hot-linking of images, for instance)*

Comment: @pix0r > Thanks :-) I generally prefer explaining "how" more than "what" : I hope it'll help people debug themselves, the next time, and believe it's more useful for everyone.

Comment: Good work Pascal MARTIN.  I did just recently enable hot link protection from my cpanel.  I just disabled it and the images now appear again.  I just noticed that I did not have https versions of my sites listed as allowed referers.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but, it could be hotlink protection too.

If you turn it on an allowed alias for a http:// domain you gotta for its https:// too, otherwise itll deny your images from being called to client.

Answer (score 0):

I used DJango API to test locally, everything is normal, after deploying SSL, the interface access is normal, but the picture shows 404

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, "not showing up" is a little vague.  If the HTML is served by HTTPS and the images are still being served by HTTP, there's a little security leak inherent in the page, which your browser may deal with in one of several, largely ineffectual, ways.

Comment: Boy, did you blow this answer.  It not only leads nowhere, the answer regarding a 'little security leak' is completely wrong.  I suggest that if you don't have a clue, don't answer.